# Is the VTC backlog only on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, review, vote-to-close, stack-exchange

I was wondering if the VTC backlog was only on Stack Overflow, or if it existed on other Stack Exchange sites. If it did exist on other sites, that might mean that the system for all Stack Exchange sites may need to be changed.

Comment: There have been many discussions on this.. but as far as I know, the VTC queue is only backlogged on SO.

Comment: Shog9 has pretty much confirm that the bulk of the SO VTC queue is the long tail of old questions, which suggests it is exclusive to SO.

Comment: I would guess that as I don't see major posts about it, but wasn't sure.

Comment: I just checked [SU], and it's at 300 something. I was more curious for the trilogy and major sites, as beta's don't usually get as much off-topic stuff.

Comment: There are a few other sites with non-zero Close Vote queues, but I wouldn't necessarily call them backlogged the same way SO is backlogged.

Comment: On most sites the toilet needs at most a little baking soda and vinegar. On SO, the entire septic tank has made itself into a backyard pool.

Comment: @random At least the kids aren't playing in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oldest pending close review task and # of pending tasks by site:

```
Oldest      Count  Site Name 
----------- ------ --------- 
Jul 10 2012 103518 StackOverflow
May 26 2013 383    SuperUser 
Dec  4 2013 40     ServerFault
Nov 11 2013 5      Cooking   
Dec  6 2013 3      Game Developers
Dec  9 2013 2      Gaming    
Dec 10 2013 2      Mathematics
Sep  2 2013 13     Photography
Dec  9 2013 1      Statistical Analysis
Oct 28 2013 72     Web Apps  
Aug 14 2012 3      Webmasters
Jan 11 2013 22     Theoretical Computer Science
Dec  8 2013 16     English Language and Usage
Nov 12 2013 1      Personal Finance and Money
Dec 10 2013 1      Role-playing Games
Dec  9 2013 2      TeX - LaTeX
Oct  1 2013 342    Ubuntu    
Dec  9 2013 4      Unix and Linux
Dec  9 2013 1      WordPress 
Nov  8 2013 8      Bicycles  
Nov 14 2013 41     Programmers
Dec  7 2013 6      Android Enthusiasts
Nov 20 2013 9      OnStartups
Dec  8 2013 1      Board and Card Games
Dec  9 2013 2      Physics   
Dec  9 2013 2      IT Security
Nov 11 2013 5      Writers   
Dec  9 2013 4      Electronics and Robotics
Dec  5 2013 12     Database Administrators
Oct  6 2013 8      Area 51 Discussions
Dec  9 2013 2      Code Review
Dec  6 2013 4      Code Golf 
Nov 15 2013 3      Project Management
Nov 25 2013 7      Skeptics  
Oct 21 2013 70     Drupal Answers
Sep  6 2013 15     Fitness and Nutrition
Nov  2 2013 4      Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair
Nov 22 2013 3      Parenting 
Dec  8 2013 1      Musical Practice and Performance
Aug 27 2013 3      Jewish Life and Learning
Nov 12 2013 1      Gardening and Landscaping
Oct  7 2013 8      Philosophy
Nov 29 2013 5      Personal Productivity
Dec  9 2013 2      Travel    
Oct 28 2013 6      Cryptography
Apr 27 2013 4      Signal Processing
Dec  7 2013 2      French Language and Usage
Dec  6 2013 10     Christianity
Sep 13 2013 34     Bitcoin   
Nov  7 2013 6      Biblical Hermeneutics
Dec  4 2013 7      History   
Dec  9 2013 1      Spanish Language and Usage
Dec  5 2013 2      Computational Science
Dec  8 2013 2      Mathematica
Sep 23 2013 12     Cognitive Sciences
Dec  9 2013 1      The Great Outdoors
Dec  9 2013 2      Sports    
Dec  9 2013 1      Academia  
Nov 17 2013 34     Computer Science
Dec  9 2013 4      The Workplace
Nov 13 2013 2      Windows Phone
Dec  2 2013 1      Chess     
Sep  3 2013 28     Raspberry Pi
Aug 12 2013 2      Islam     
Dec 26 2012 32     Patents   
Dec  9 2013 1      User Experience
Aug 22 2013 2      Genealogy and Family History
Nov  8 2013 2      Robotics  
Oct 22 2013 6      Politics  
Aug  6 2013 6      Audio-Video Production
Dec  9 2013 1      English Language Learners
Dec  5 2013 1      Tridion Stack Exchange
Nov 10 2013 5      Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange
Nov  8 2013 2      Open Data Stack Exchange
Jun  4 2013 2      Freelancing Stack Exchange
Dec  8 2013 2      Blender Stack Exchange
Dec  7 2013 4      MathOverflow
```

(sites with no pending close review tasks omitted)

Comment: Clearly, there's a backlog on all those sites, just not as bad.

Comment: Even the largest of the backlogs on Ubuntu and SU are trivial in comparison though.