# Is the Meta SE FAQ sidebar broken?

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, sidebar

In the sidebar, under FAQ/"Frequently Asked" (and not the "Featured on Meta" section), the link to the featured post [What criteria should we use to determine which review queue indicator a site will have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305893/270345) is showing up wrong:

[image: "Frequently Asked" first entry with wrong link]

The mouse pointer is not visible, but it's on the "What criteria should we use to determine which review queue indicator a site will have?"

The link points to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil
which itself redirects to deleted post 3511:

```
~ curl -LI https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3513/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil
HTTP/2 301
date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 01:51:02 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
location: /questions/3511/i-thought-that-the-google-openid-problem-was-fixed/3513#3513
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: b1b849bd-972f-46f7-a889-5654727e26e0
strict-transport-security: max-age=86400
accept-ranges: bytes
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 0
x-served-by: cache-itm18830-ITM
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1517190662.944105,VS0,VE190
vary: Fastly-SSL
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
set-cookie: prov=dca0a7b7-3b72-9780-6b4e-4b249e70973c; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
cache-control: private
content-length: 193

HTTP/2 404
date: Mon, 29 Jan 2018 01:51:02 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
x-request-guid: 0f0f7c00-8d04-4162-b8de-23200a43185e
strict-transport-security: max-age=86400
accept-ranges: bytes
via: 1.1 varnish
age: 0
x-served-by: cache-itm18830-ITM
x-cache: MISS
x-cache-hits: 0
x-timer: S1517190662.147987,VS0,VE192
vary: Fastly-SSL
x-dns-prefetch-control: off
set-cookie: prov=4e655d08-e5f6-4e69-40cd-061ae2053205; domain=.stackexchange.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
cache-control: private
content-length: 57326
```

Not sure what's going on. Other links in that list work fine.

Comment: :( Happening on all my devices - opening in desktop mode in Android and iPhone Chrome, also on Firefox on Ubuntu and Chrome and Firefox on a Mac. But all devices are in Japan, so maybe a regionalised caching issue?

Comment: Probably that. For me in English (US) it links to 305893.

Comment: Tried both private window and a browser where I wasn't logged into MSE.  And on `lynx` on a system in India I SSH'd to. :(

Comment: Yes, it is broken, as I'm getting the same result. This bug was already reported on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360703/6083675), but now we know it's probably happening everywhere.

Comment: @Laurel thanks! And as noted by Floern there, the post ID I'm seeing is indeed that of the featured tag - [3513](https://meta.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/3513).

Comment: Ah, I was looking in the wrong place. I can repro even in English (US).

Comment: @Laurel odd edit that.... Even odder edit summary.

Comment: @muru Ah, I guess I made a mistake there.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek You were probably clicking on the wrong link. I've edited in a freehand circle to point to the right link.

Comment: One thing to note: the stub doesn't matter. The post ID determines which page you land on. (In other words, the redirect is expected behavior.) So the problem is that the sidebar link has the wrong post number for some reason.

Comment: @JonEricson the redirect is probably because the deleted question is a dupe (note that it's redirecting from 3513 to 3511)

Comment: 3513 is probably an answer to 3511. Post IDs are shared between questions and answers. (@JonEricson)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about that; during a bit of cleanup aimed at improving site startup time a few weeks back a small error crept into the query responsible for generating those links... Well, it ended up tossing multiple Id columns into the results, and the wrong one got picked for the Id of the post.

This is now fixed.