# Review queue indicator not firing in the top bar even though reviews are available on a small SE site

Tags: bug, review, top-bar

The top bar on Webmasters didn't say there were reviews, but when I clicked the queues icon, I see that there are reviews to be completed:

[image]

- I hadn't checked the queues in over an hour
- The question in the close vote queue had its close vote for over an hour according to the review history log.

In [What criteria should we use to determine which review queue indicator a site will have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305893/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil) [Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/1438/jon-ericson) asked me to raise an issue if I continue to see this behavior.

It isn't always broken, I sometimes get the notification:

[image]

The behavior seem erratic.   Most recently there was a suggested edit and a first post with no top bar notification.

Comment: Can you actually review these items? When you click on "Close votes" is there anything there? What browser are you using?

Comment: There was one item in the close vote queue and I was able to review it.   I'm using a Firefox 27 spinoff called Palemoon.   I'll check with more popular browsers as well.

Comment: Yeah, if it works in a supported browser, then I'll say it's probably just that that one isn't supported.

Comment: I just saw the same behavior in Chrome, but I'll have to wait an hour to be sure it isn't caused by the one hour rule on that indicator.

Comment: I can duplicate the issue on Webmasters right now. I'll pass it onto a dev and see if there's a bug here.

Comment: @JonEricson Just happened to me and someone else at TGO today - any news on this?