# Review-needed indicator is trigger happy

Tags: discussion, support, review, top-bar

Since I recently gained 2K, and quickly thereafter 3k reputation here on MSE the review queues became accessible to me. Every now and then I check on them to see if there is something that needs reviewing.

When I notice a red icon I'm under the impression that there are a lot of reviews to be done, but every time I get disappointed when after 1 review the queue is empty again. So I decided to look for the logic behind the different states of the review-needed indicator, which led me to [this announcement by Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly). In which there is stated that the default values for the red button are:

> ```
> Queue                 Default
> -----          --------------  
> Close                      20
> Reopen                      5
> Low Quality                 4
> Suggested Edits             3
> ....                      ...
> ```

Apparently this isn't the case, so what exactly causes the review-needed indicator to turn red the instant there is a review item?

Secondly, is it desirable that there is always a red flag, instead of the gray flag when there simply is something to review.

**Regarding the suggestion that a filter might limit the amount of review tasks available:**

In that case there is a message displayed: [image: Message of review queue stating: "There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[Filter]""]

> There are no items for you to review, matching the filter "[discussion]"

Comment: AFAIK the thresholds are adjusted per site, based on the average queue sizes. That table might be outdated ... [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305893/295232) is an update on the algorithm.

Comment: It is also possible that the review queues appear to be empty, when you have a tag filter applied. Then there are no more reviews matching your filter, but the queue is still not empty.

Comment: @Glorfindel that would be the answer I guess.

Comment: Sure; if the information in that question fully addresses your question(s), feel free to close it as a duplicate. It took me a while to find the right question, so this is definitely a useful signpost.