# Can we change the design of the reviews' indicator in the top bar?

Tags: feature-request, design, review, top-bar

In the old days, we used to have a number when there were reviews that need to be done. I understand why that had to go. I'm not asking to bring it back. But one issue that I've noticed with myself, at least, is that I review a lot less than I used to before. I find that the current indicator isn't as much inviting as it used to be.

I suppose there needs to be a balance between how annoying and how inviting it should be.

This is how it currently looks like when there no reviews available.

[image: Top-bar icons - No reviews available]

And this is how it currently looks like when there's at least one queue that has reached the "upper threshold" (i.e. has the red dot instead of the grey one).

[image: Top-bar icons - Lots of reviews available]

One very subtle proposition I have, in the second status, i.e. where there are reviews available, would it be possible to drop the checkmark from the icon and only show it when the reviews are all done?

I'm not saying this is the solution but just one idea that might have a small impact. I reason that checkmarks are usually linked to tasks that are done.

Ps. I'm not sure how the indicator looks when there reviews available, but none of them is red. But I suppose it's the same as the second screenshot, but it's a grey dot instead of a red one.

<sub>*Disclaimer, this was prompted by [a meta-question regarding the suggested edits queue](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19602/can-we-increase-the-capacity-of-our-suggested-edits-queue) on Ask Ubuntu. As I realised then how I had almost stopped reviewing compared to the early days.*</sub>

Comment: If there are reviews available but not enough to trigger the threshold, it looks like the upper image - no indicator at all. We can configure these per-site but we tend to put sites in buckets based on size rather than making the bucket size specific to the site only. There are a bunch of discussions about this back when it was changed in 2017 - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304445/experiment-review-needed-indicator-logic-for-sites-that-sometimes-have-empty-qu

Comment: Possibly more directly related - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305893/what-criteria-should-we-use-to-determine-which-review-queue-indicator-a-site-wil

Comment: @Catija Thanks, for the links! But just to be clearer, I'm not asking to change thresholds nor change how the dots behave. I'm just asking if it would be possible to remove the checkmark that's at the bottom right of the reviews icon in the top bar when there are reviews to be made.

Comment: I just found out that it's possible not to have the red dot at all even if there are reviews to be made; by clicking the icon and navigating away from the page. I wonder when it will show up again though https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wpk7n.png

Comment: It's dismissed for an hour - that's by design. I don't think we would dynamically change the icon based on the status, no. The thing is, there's a difference between when the reviews are all done and when the reviews *available to you* are done.

Comment: @Catija I see, and I don't suppose the checkmark can also be dropped completely in that case as the review will look a bit like the Stack Exchange icon

Comment: You might notice in the links I shared from 2017/18 that the image used to be quite different - we got to the icon we did through a ton of community discussion, so I don't think that we'd want to change it. People have strong feelings about what it looks like and this was the preferred icon at the time.