# What is the threshold for the review-needed indicator (the red circle) in the First Questions and First Answers?

Tags: support, review, new-users, top-bar

In the dropdown for review, we sometimes have an indicator (red circle) showing that there are many reviews - and that this particular review queue needs attention.

The thresholds are mentioned in this post: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226) ([current revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/302226/9)).  But this post was created before the queue for First Posts was split into First Answers and First Questions. (This was announced in August 2021: [Review queue workflows - Final release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369013).)

- What are the thresholds for this indicator in the First Answers and First Questions review queues?
- Are the other numbers in Jon Ericson's answer above still valid? (Have they been changed since then?)

Comment: I decided to ask about this after seeing this question on [math.meta.se]: [Why red instead of grey in review queue?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35081) The question seems a bit unclear to me - but since the screenshot shows "First questions" as an example, I wanted at least check what is supposed to be threshold there - and then I found out that these review queues are not listed in the relevant thread: [How does the review-needed indicator work exactly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226)

Comment: Those are tuned per site, so *What are the thresholds for this indicator* might return an answer with all 182 sites and their meta, right?

Comment: @rene Isn't this different only on "small" sites - with some (big) sites having the same default values? At least this is the impression after a cursory reading of this: [Experiment: Review-needed indicator logic for sites that sometimes have empty queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/304445) and [What criteria should we use to determine which review queue indicator a site will have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305893) (But I have to admit that before your message I did not consider possibility that different sites have different values.)

Comment: Yeah, I expect there to be reasonable defaults to be set by the CM team. But I know Shog9 tweaked that setting on this very site because the defaults weren't working out as intended. So I don't expect that each site has its own setting but there isn't a single threshold either. We wait and see what Animuson or a CM has to tell about this.

Comment: @rene For the most part, the sites are one of the three default levels. It's something that's been on my mind to work more on customizing per-site because (as you might be able to tell from some of the questions Martin linked) I'm not super happy with the existing solution :P But we need a lot more data to figure out the right indicator levels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current default thresholds for these review queues are 5 for First Posts, and 5 for First Answers. (Which I suppose makes sense, since each of those queues ostensibly has half as many items now.)

The other defaults are the same as listed in that post – aside from the fact that the Help & Improvement queue no longer exists.

(And of course, these are just the default values; they may be different on individual sites.)